# TypeError: Cannot read property '' of undefined on Saga tests

Tags: reactjs, jasmine, jestjs, redux-saga

I am running tests using jest for my react code which also includes sagas. 
My all tests are passing but I am getting an interesting `console.error` as following. What is a mistake on following code?

Here is my console when running tests

```
console.error node_modules/redux-saga/lib/internal/utils.js:240
  uncaught at rootSaga at rootSaga 
   at rootSaga 
   TypeError: Cannot read property 'FETCH_ORDERS_REQUEST' of undefined
      at FETCH_ORDERS_REQUEST (..../redux/sagas.js:38:25)
      at Object.<anonymous>.exports.default.next (<anonymous>)
      at next (.../node_modules/redux-saga/lib/internal/proc.js:322:27)
      at proc (..../node_modules/redux-saga/lib/internal/proc.js:281:3)
      at resolveIterator (.../node_modules/redux-saga/lib/internal/proc.js:467:5)
      at runEffect (/.../node_modules/redux-saga/lib/internal/proc.js:443:178)
```

sagas.js:

```
import { call, put, takeEvery, all } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import * as loadboardAPI from 'api/loadboard';
import * as ordersAPI from 'api/orders';
import * as actions from './actions';
import * as types from './types';

export function* fetchOrders({ query }) {
    try {
        const response = yield call(loadboardAPI.searchOrders, adaptedQuery);
        const orders = response.data.objects;

        yield put(actions.fetchOrdersSuccess(orders));
    } catch (error) {
        yield put(actions.fetchOrdersFailure(error));
    }
}
...
        export default function*() {
        yield all([
            takeEvery(types.FETCH_ORDERS_REQUEST, fetchOrders),
            ....
        ]);
    }
```

Failing part of sagas.test.js

```
import { all, call, put, takeEvery } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import * as loadboardAPI from 'api/loadboard';
import * as actions from './actions';
import * as types from './types';
import * as sagas from './sagas';

describe('default', () => {
        const saga = sagas.default();
        const output = saga.next().value;
        const expected = all([
            takeEvery(types.FETCH_ORDERS_REQUEST, sagas.fetchOrders),
        ]);

        expect(output).toEqual(expected);
    });
```

Comment: I had the same error, and it's gone once I removed cross - references from saga files. I.e. one of my file did `export const blaBla = ''`, I moved it out from sagas (into general place), and this error gone. However, I'm not sure what is the root case of that.

Comment: cross referencing can definitely cause similar issues. i've run into problems with the redux store trying to boot up during a test and causing undefined errors. the tests still run and successfully pass/fail, but it does create a lot of noise in the logs